# Смена вида кастомного item в ListView

Tags: android, listview, java

Делаю кастомные item'ы для ListView таким вот образом:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, constants);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Вот разметка list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listitem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#4d73ff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Но как мне изменить, например, цвет фона кастомного item кодом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инициализировать слой

`LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listitem"`

в классе - LinearLayout listItem;

```
в onCreate:
    listItem = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.listitem);
    listItem.setBackgroundColor(R.color.НАЗВАНИЕ_ЦВЕТА_В_ФАЙЛЕ_РЕСУРСОВ);
/** или 
* listItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); */
```

**UPD**

```
lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); // к примеру, белый цвет.
```

Comment: @Perkovec, нет. LinearLayout listItem; после импортов.

Comment: @web_alex, не пашет, ругается на эту строчку
listitem.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 0, 0));
пишет java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Perkovec, так нужно же задавать для listItem(слой в xml), а не для listitem(разметки xml).

Comment: @web_alex, я понимаю, просто букву попутал

Comment: @web_alex, тем не менее это ничего не изменило

Comment: @Perkovec, нужно поменять цвет всех item'ов или каждого отдельно (при нажатии, к примеру)?

Comment: @web_alex, менять всех

Comment: @Perkovec, обновил ответ.